# How to calculate number of possible combinations of an array?

Tags: combinatorics

I have an array (programming array, not math array) that contains 32 items made up of 4 different types wherein there must always be exactly 8 items of each type. And, of course, order matters in arrays. If I shuffled this array, how would I calculate how many possible combinations exist?

Comment: So you ask for the number of arrangements of AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDD?  This is a textbook example of a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Comment: Your question was about "how many ways" which is a question about enumerative combinatorics.  Nowhere in your question does the concept of probability come up at all.

Comment: What would you do with 2 each of 4 types?

Comment: @JMoravitz oh cool thanks, so if my math is correct then `99,561,092,450,391,000` permutations? Did I compute that correctly?

Comment: Yes, though whether the answer is more useful in the form of $\approx 9.956\cdot 10^{16}$ or if it is more useful in the form of $\binom{32}{8,8,8,8}$ or as $\frac{32!}{(8!)^4}$ depends on context.  I would be able to immediately tell at a glance that $\binom{32}{8,8,8,8}$ is correct.  I had to plug that in to a calculator and compare to $99561\dots000$ to tell if yours was correct and would not have been able to verify without a calculator.

Comment: @JMoravitz so 99 quadrillion for an array with just 32 items! That's freaking cool. Thanks for the help!